# Is the direct connection from Helsinki-Vantaa Airport to the train line open yet?

Tags: airport-transfer, train-stations, helsinki, hel

When the [Ring Rail Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_Rail_Line) to Helsinki-Vantaa Int'l Airport opened in July 2015, the Airport station wasn't ready yet and passengers had to be bussed in from the nearest station.  Even when the station opened a few months later, the exit connecting to the terminal wasn't opened, so you had to keep using the bus or hike a good 500 meters to the exit at the "wrong" end.

The direct connection was supposed to open in "early 2016".  It's now January, **is it open yet**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it's open!**

And I can confirm the escalators and lifts are also open from the airport direct to the train platform.

[image: Ring Rail Line map]

Map credit: [Helsinki Region Transport](https://www.hsl.fi/en/ringrailline)

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**, it's open!  The escalator between the terminal and the station is *still* not ready (latest estimate "spring 2016"), but [on December 18 they at least opened two elevators](http://www.liikennevirasto.fi/-/keharata-lentoaseman-terminaalisisaankaynti-avataan-koekayttoon-18-12-2015-rakennustyot-lentoaseman-juna-asemalla-jatkuvat-liukuportaiden-osalta#.VpGlPpN95E4) that connect directly from the walkway between T1/T2 to the station.

Comment: Excellent news! I suppose you won't be in Australia in the following weeks then.

Comment: Awesome! I was searching that few days ago.